# Firebase deploy error - Cannot find module 'firebase'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy Google Cloud function triggers that trigger from db events, but when I run `firebase deploy` The functions aren't deployed properly and I get an error saying `Error: Cannot find module firebase`

When I was first creating the project I could deploy functions without any issues. It's been a few days since I last deployed anything, but now I'm getting this issue on all my functions (not just my trigger functions)

My function:

```
exports.deleteNotificationOnUnlike = functions
    .region("us-central1")
    .firestore.document("likes/{id}")
    .onDelete((snapshot) => {
        return db
            .doc(`/notifications/${snapshot.id}`)
            .delete()
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    });
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "busboy": "^0.3.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Expecting the functions to deploy successfully but getting this error:

Error messages from firebase:

```
Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'firebase'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/handlers/users.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"},"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"*********"},"requestMetadata":{"requestAttributes":{},"destinationAttributes":{}},"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com","methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction","resourceName":"projects/*******/locations/us-central1/functions/createNotificationOnComment"}
```

I've seen some posts where people were missing some modules and needed to run an `npm i XXX` inside the functions folder, but I haven't seen any instances where it was saying that the firebase module couldn't be found, and I'm not sure what changes from my last successful deployment, or what module I might be missing.

Comment: Once try to delete `node_modules` and run `npm install` again. Also try to use latest `firebase` package.

Comment: I don't see where in your code that you're actually trying to make use of the firebase module.  Also, your package.json doesn't even show that it's installed.  Lastly, you probably shouldn't be using the firebase module at all, as that's for frontend apps.  Backend code, like what you deploy to Cloud Functions, would typically just make use of firebase-admin.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Figured out the solution. I hadn't installed the firebase module in the functions folder but had included it in the parent folder of `functions`. I went into functions and ran `npm install --save firebase` and the deploy was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed the package from the functions directory, Not the project directory. I got this error many times when I accidentally installed packages while in the project directory, It worked fine locally, but created such errors during deployment. So, goto functions and install from there

```
cd functions
npm install [your package]
```

Then it usually works fine

Answer (score -2):

Try updating firebase npm package, mine was solved using `npm install -D firebase`.

-Stay Safe!